# d3 graph - How do I make the JS get the JSON from PHP script and then select axes and plot?

Tags: php, json, d3.js

I have a JSON output from a php file called "getdata.php". This script retrieves data from the database.

The output is as follows:

```
{"datex":"2013-02-19","value":"0"}{"datex":"2013-02-20","value":"1"}...
```

I need to plot a linegraph using d3 of date vs sentiment.

I have tried editing this - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195#index.html - but I don't understand which part of the javascript I have to edit.

How do I make the JS get the data from getdata.php and then select x axis and y axis and plot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`d3.json`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) instead of `d3.tsv` which that example is using.

You code would then look something like:

```
d3.json('getdata.php', function(json) {
    // Same code here as in the tsv example.
});
```

See [this](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/2322933) example for more hints on how to use d3.json.